# AndroidAssets image loading for different resolution and memory

Tags: android, assets

I have used different resolution images in my game to support different screen sizes and different memory bitmap memory capabilities. However, it makes the application quickly become quite large as all the images are stored three times in the application with different resolutions.

I saw that there exists now methods such a `setAssetScale` and `setBitmapOptionsAdjuster` that seems to address this issue, as the Javadoc says:

> This allows one to use higher resolution imagery than the device might normally.

However, I didn't find any documentation or sample showing exactly how to use these methods. Does anyone have more information about this, or some sample code?